# Подключение OCI Oracle в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, oracle, visual-c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, 4 день что то уже мучаюсь, пытаюсь хотя хотя бы как подключить все необходимые файлы OCI Oracle в Visual Studio 2017.
Читаю или пытаюсь понять вот эту инструкцию от Oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10779/oci01int.htm#423364

Но ничего не могу понять: там сказано, что:
-Библиотеки Instant Client также можно загрузить с otn.oracle.comвеб-сайта Oracle Technology Network ( ).
-Приложение OCI работает в режиме мгновенного клиента... В этом режиме нет зависимости, ORACLE_HOME и никакой другой код и файлы данных, предоставленные в нем, ORACLE_HOME - не нужны OCI.

Пишут, что в этом режиме нет зависимости,  ORACLE_HOME - не нужны OCI и тут же пишут, что:
-В Windows:
-oraociei10.dll библиотека находится в ORACLE_HOME\instantclient
-oci.dll, ociw32.dll, orannzsbb10.dll в ORACLE_HOME\bin

Потом пишут, что:
-Для разработки необходима полная установка для доступа к заголовочным файлам OCI, Makefiles.

То есть тех трех указанных dll - oraociei10.dll, oci.dll, ociw32.dll, orannzsbb10.dll - недостаточно ?

Вообще не понятно, что делать нужно :((((

Comment: Нашел файлы:
-oci.h
-oci.lib
-oci.dll

Вроде как подключил их:
#include <D:\\Oracle distibute\\18\\oci.h>
 
#pragma comment(lib, "D:\\Oracle distibute\\18\\oci.lib")
oci.dll скопировал в папке с самим exe-шником.

Но VS2017 все равно ругается:

E1696   не удается открыть источник файл "oratypes.h"   Oracle_connect  D:\Oracle distibute\18\oci.h    713
E1696   не удается открыть источник файл "ocidfn.h" Oracle_connect  D:\Oracle distibute\18\oci.h    717 
E1696   не удается открыть источник файл "ociver.h" Oracle_connect  D:\Oracle distibute\18\oci.h    721 
...итд

Comment: Повидимому вы путаете окружение для запуска приложения и окружение для его разработки. Для компиляции вам нужно установить полный клиент, там все заголовочные файлы.

Comment: 0xdb, Спасибо, но вот тут:[ссылка](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html), что достаточно только intant Client Oracle: Все файлы, необходимые для запуска приложений OCI, OCCI и JDBC: OCI

Comment: Точно, SDK можно дополнительно поставить, там всё есть. Все равно не помогло?

Comment: 0xdb, я вот и пытался подключить эти dll-ки в том числе. Но что то видимо не так делаю.

Comment: Так осталось не понятным, вы запускаете приложение или пытаетесь его собрать? Как вы указывате пути к include/ и lib/ в SDK? ORACLE_HOME это просто переменная окружения, содержащая полный путь к клиенту. Никто кроме вас не знает, куда вы его установили. Когда пишут, что нет зависимости, то имеют ввиду, что эту переменную никто не читает.

Comment: 0xdb, вообщем я скачал Instant Client Oracle для Windows - [ссылка](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html) - оттуда взял, как я понял из документации - [ссылка](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnoci/instant-client.html#GUID-6895DB45-97AA-4738-9959-BD677D610186) - 4 dll файла: oci.dll, oraociei19.dll, orannzsbb19.dll и oraons.dll. В Visual Studio 2017 с помощью функции LoadLibraryW указал к ним путь:>HINSTANCE hMyDLL_oci  =LoadLibraryW(L"D://Oracle distibute//Oracle_DLL//oci.dll");

Comment: 0xdb, и все, дальше опять непонятно, что делать.

Comment: _дальше опять непонятно, что делать_, потому, что вы так и не ответили на вопрос -  _вы запускаете приложение или пытаетесь его собрать?_. Если вы не знаете - _что делаете_, вы не сможете понять - _что делать дальше_ .